# @Convert in DataNucleus

Tags: java, jpa, datanucleus

Did anyone managed to use @Convert annotation with DataNucleus? Do you have a working example or a documentation link?

I tried to implement it this way

```
...
@Convert(converter = MyAttributeConverter.class)
private String[] aField;
...
```

`MyAttributeConverter` implements `javax.persistence.jpa21.AttributeConverter<String[], String>`.

When I run the DataNucleus Enhancer I get this error

```
WARN [main] (Log4JLogger.java:96) - Class "XXX" has an annotation "javax.persistence.jpa21.Convert" specified with property "converter" yet this is invalid. Please check the specification for that annotation class. Errors were encountered when loading the specified MetaData files and classes. See the nested exceptions for details
ERROR [main] (Log4JLogger.java:125) - DataNucleus Enhancer completed with an error. Please review the enhancer log for full details. Some classes may have been enhanced but some caused errors Errors were encountered when loading the specified MetaData files and classes. See the nested exceptions for details org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Errors were encountered when loading the specified MetaData files and classes. See the nested exceptions for details
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.loadClasses(MetaDataManager.java:536)
    ...
```

According to DataNucleus documentation seems fine: http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/jpa/annotations.html#Convert, though googling I found an issue report in which things are a little bit different: http://www.datanucleus.org/servlet/jira/browse/NUCJPA-164.

I'm using DataNucleus 3.1.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meantime I upgraded to datanucleus-accessplatform-jpa-rdbms 3.3.2 (datanucleus-core 3.2.7, datanucleus-api-jpa 3.3.2) and I made it work.

But that message can be for various reasons:

- You can have the converter class missing from classpath.
- Your converter could be inherited from another class - see my other question [Base class for JPA converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767889/base-class-for-jpa-converter) (not yet answered though)
- There could be an incompatibility between the converter entity type and the field type to which the @Convert annotation is used.
- There could be an incompatibility between versions. E.g. your converter could implement `javax.persistence.jpa21.AttributeConverter` (older versions), but the enhancer is using `javax.persistence.AttributeConverter` (newer versions) or the other way around.

I think that the error message should be a little bit more specific to help you better identify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Samples are under http://datanucleus.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/datanucleus/test/accessplatform/trunk/test.jpa.general/src/java/org/jpox/samples/typeconversion/ and test at
http://datanucleus.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/datanucleus/test/accessplatform/trunk/test.jpa.general/src/test/org/datanucleus/tests/TypeConversionTest.java?revision=16466&view=markup

Comment: I did the same thing, but as you saw from my question above it doesn't work.

Comment: and obviously in our case it does work, and that is run every time any tests are run. Yours says look at the nested exception, so only you know where the exception was thrown from, and consequently you can look at the line of code as to why that may be

Comment: Checking the test cases for samples is an incredible idea ! Would you please help find test cases for `JDO/RDBMS` ? I seem to only hit `JPOX` samples !