# Base class for JPA converter

Tags: java, jpa, datanucleus

I have the following code

```
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;

public class MyBaseConverter implements AttributeConverter<MyType, String> {
    // implement the required methods
    ...
}

public class MyConverter extends MyBaseConverter {
    // no methods in this class
}
```

Why `@Convert(converter = MyBaseConverter.class)` works, but `@Convert(converter = MyConverter.class)` doesn't?

In the second case I get an error while running the enhancer. I did some debugging and it seems that in the class `JPAAnnotationReader` line 1966 (datanucleus-api-jpa-3.3.2.jar)

```
if (typeMgr.getTypeConverterForName(converterCls.getName()) == null)
```

`converterCls` is null and throws NPE in the second case, but not the first.

Is it a bug in DataNucleus?

Comment: I filled in a bug report http://www.datanucleus.org/servlet/jira/browse/NUCACCESS-117

Comment: This is clearly a DataNucleus issues. I also provided the fix for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In DataNucleus there's a bug for this. I filled in a bug report http://datanucleus.org/servlet/jira/browse/NUCACCESS-117. Please follow up there to check in which release will be included.